# Jquery counter is counting to desired number but then starts reverse counting too

Tags: jquery

Here is my jquery code. It counts to the given number but then starts reverse counting.... i have also added $('.count').remove at the end of the code but it didn't worked.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

 $('.count').each(function() {

 $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
  Counter: $(this).text()
 }, {
  duration: 4000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function(now) {
    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
   }         
  });
 });   
})
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your code.

Comment: What does your DOM look like? And what is your expected output?

Comment: Can you post your html code as well?

Comment: Here is my html code.

<div id="crcle"><span class="count">1000</span>

Comment: Without having tested the details, I think a problem is that the previous animation is never stopped. While scrolling the animation is started multiple times. You could try using `$(this).stop().prop(...etc` inside the each. (Don't know if it solves the problem at hand though)

Comment: It didn't work... i have also tried that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `complete:` after the `step:`

e.g.

```
$({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: 100}, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
        $(this).text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
        $(this).addClass('loaded');
    }
});
```

Comment: I just mentioned the complete function. It must be modified as needed.